# C# and strange exponentiation of complex numbers

Tags: c#, mono

Have been playing around with complex numbers in C#, and I found something interesting. Not sure if its a bug or if I have just missed something, but when I run the following code:

```
var num = new Complex(0, 1);
var complexPow = Complex.Pow(num, 2);
var numTimesNum = num * num;
Console.WriteLine("Complex.Pow(num, 2) = {0}   num*num = {1}", complexPow.ToString(), numTimesNum.ToString());
```

I get the following output:

```
Complex.Pow(num, 2) = (-1, 1.22460635382238E-16)   num*num = (-1, 0)
```

If memory serves, a complex number times itself should be just -1 with no imaginary part (or rather an imaginary part of 0). So why doesnt Complex.Pow(num, 2) give -1? Where does the 1.22460635382238E-16 come from?

If it matters, I am using mono since Im not in Windows atm. Think it might be 64-bit, since I am running a 64-bit OS, but I am not sure where to check.

Take care,
Kerr.

EDIT:

Ok, I explained poorly. I of course mean the square of i is -1, not the square of any complex number. Thanks for pointing it out. A bit tired right now, so my brain doesnt work too well, lol.

EDIT 2:

To clarify something, I have been reading a little math lately and decided to make a small scripting language for fun. Ok, "scripting language" is an over statement, it just evaluates equations and nothing more.

Comment: i^2 is -1. However, ai^2 is (-1)*a.

Comment: Also note: On Intel based processors sin and cos is completely unreliable for values bigger than 9e18 and -9e18. Details can be read on http://www.intel.com/design/processor/manuals/253665.pdf under 8.1.3.2 Condition Code Flags specifying the limit of FSIN and friends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're seeing floating-point imprecision.

`1.22460635382238E-16` is actually `0.00000000000000012...`.

`Complex.Pow()` is probably implemented through [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), using trigonometry to compute arbitrary powers.
It is therefore subject to inaccuracy from both floating-point arithmetic and trig.
It apparently does not have any special-case code for integral powers, which can be simpler.

Ordinary [complex multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_numbers#Multiplication_and_division) only involves simple arithmetic, so it is not subject to floating-point inaccuracies when the numbers are integral.

Comment: Thanks for the link to De Moivres formula. Didnt know about it.

Answer (score 7):

> So why doesnt Complex.Pow(num, 2) give -1? Where does the 1.22460635382238E-16 come from?

I suspect it's a rounding error, basically. It's a very small number, after all. I don't know the details of `Complex.Pow`, but I wouldn't be at all surprised to find it used some trigonometry somewhere - you may well be observing the fact that pi/2 isn't exactly representable as a double.

The `*` operation is able to avoid this by being more simply defined - `Complex.Pow` *could* be special-cased to just use `x * x` where the power is 2, but I expect that hasn't been done. Instead, a general algorithm is used which gives an answer *very close* to the hypothetical one, but which can result in small errors.

Comment: It's worth noting that the primary reason you *can't* implement `Pow` in terms of repeated multiplication (beyond just efficiency issues) is that `Pow` needs to support non-integer numbers.  You can't multiply a number with itself 1.5 times.

Comment: That sounds right. Is there any way to solve this? As I mentioned in my edited post, its for a small "scripting language" and I would prefer if I could find a more accurate way to handle exponentiation.

Comment: @Servy Which is one of the things I need to be able to do. What I could do is perhaps to "cheat" a little and rewrite integer exponents to multiplications, even if I am not sure how to do it at this point :p.

Answer (score 3):

> So why doesnt Complex.Pow(num, 2) give -1? Where does the 1.22460635382238E-16 come from?

Standard issues with [floating point representations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), and the algorithms that are used to compute `Complex.Pow` (it's not as simple as you think). Note that `1.22460635382238E-16` is extremely small, close to machine epsilon. Additionally, a key fact here is that `(0, 1)` is really `(1, pi / 2)` in polar coordinates, and `pi / 2` doesn't have an exact representation in floating point.

If this is at all uncomfortable to you, I recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It *should* be required reading for college CS curriculum.